# BroadCast message over ip python windows 10

Tags: python, broadcast

I am trying to write a simple messenger that sends a broadcast msg to all the computer in the local network . The code works on windows 7 , Ubuntu 14.10 but when I am trying to use it on windows 10 , it even does not send an udp package to broadcast , its doing nothing (checked with wireshark, no outgoing packages)

```
import socket
import sys
import traceback

dest=('<broadcast>',10100)
UDPSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

UDPSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
while True:
    data = raw_input("Enter message to send or type 'exit': ")
    UDPSock.sendto(data, dest)
    if data == "exit":
        break
UDPSock.close()
```

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recognized the same problem after updating to Win10.
My WOL.py (Wakeup On Lan) does not work any more.
Checked with tcpdump.

I found now a workaround.

```
# Broadcast it to the LAN.
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sock.sendto(send_data, ('172.16.1.255', 9)
```

Changing the address from `'<broadcast>'` to the network address with broadcast bit's set works on my system.

E.g. I have a Class C Network with IP 172.16.1.x netmask 255.255.255.0. Changing `'<broadcast>'`to `'172.16.1.255'` does the trick. Normally this is done by the OS.

PS.: Sorry for the wrong posting, last time.

Comment: This is not an answer.  You should leave in comments.  If you can't comment, wait until you can

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for the work around.  I'm on a Class C network with 192.168.1.X.  I used 192.168.1.255 and could see the broadcast packets working perfectly.